# Sobel Operator in Julia

Tags: image-processing, julia, sobel

I am beginner regarding Julia programming and I want to implement Sobel operator. Unfortunately the output of the following code is just a black image.

```
using Images, Colors, FileIO, Plots;
img = load("Lenna.png");
img_gray = Gray.(img);
sobel_image = convert(Array{Float64}, img_gray);
kernel_x =  Array{Float64}([1 0 -1; 2 0 -2; 1 0 -1]);
kernel_y =  Array{Float64}([1 2 1; 0 0 0; -1 -2 -1]);

#plot(img_gray)
function sobel(img)
    edge_img = zeros(Gray{Float64}, size(img, 1), size(img, 2));
    for x in 1:size(edge_img, 1) - size(kernel_x,1)
        for y in 1:size(edge_img, 2) - size(kernel_y,2)
            gx = sum(Gray{Float64}.(
                @view edge_img[x:x+size(kernel_x,1)-1, y:y+size(kernel_y,2)-1]) .* kernel_x)
            gy = sum(Gray{Float64}.(
                    @view edge_img[x:x+size(kernel_x,1)-1, y:y+size(kernel_y,2)-1]) .* kernel_y)
            edge_img[x+1, y+1] = hypot(gx, gy)
        end
    end
    return edge_img;
end

last_image = sobel(sobel_image)
plot(last_image)
```

I converted `kernel_x` and `kernel_y` to Array64. The basic idea was to convert code from python to Julia since i do not know the syntax. Could you help me with some tips?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code could use some editing (unnecessary type calls, global variables, etc), but I don't think much of it is responsible for the erroneous result.

It looks like your `sobel` function takes in an `img`, but it only uses it in the first line to create a black (all 0s) `edge_img`, then only works on `edge_img` for the rest of the function. I think that's why you end up with a black image. Perhaps you meant to index values from `img` in the `gx = ...` and `gy = ...` lines?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `ImageFiltering`:

```
using ImageFiltering, TestImages, Plots
im = testimage("cameraman")
kernel = [1 0 -1; 2 0 -2;1 0 -1]
ims = imfilter(im, kernel)

Plots.plot(hcat(im, ims))
```

[image]